# How to create proper xml for SOAP Client function?

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap-client

I've spend hours with SOAPClient and still get no result, hope someone can help me. I'm trying to create and send to web-service following code:

```
POST /PortalServices/PortalServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host:***.***.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://***.com/CreateUser"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <UserCredentials xmlns="http://***.com/">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <PassWord>string</PassWord>
      <ServiceName>string</ServiceName>
    </UserCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateUser xmlns="http://***.com/">
      <user>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <Email>string</Email>
        <PassWord>string</PassWord>
        <WsServices>
          <WsService>
            <Id>int</Id>
          </WsService>
        </WsServices>
      </user>
    </CreateUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To get this xml I use the following code:

```
<?php

class WsService {
public $Id = "****";
}

class WsServices {
public $WsService;
public function __construct() {
         $this->WsService = new WsService();
        }
}


class WsUser {

public $Name = 'Sasha Lavasov';
public $Email = 'imsashko@gmail.com';
public $PassWord = 'test';
public $WsServices;

public function __construct() {
        $this->WsServices = new WsService();
        }
}

   $ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

   $soap_url = 'http://***.***.com/PortalServices/PortalServices.asmx?wsdl';
   $soapClient = new \SoapClient($soap_url, array(
       'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
       'trace' => 1,
       'exceptions' => true,
       'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
       ));

   $hdd = new stdClass();
   $hdd->UserName =   '***';
   $hdd->PassWord = '***';
   $hdd->ServiceName = '***';

   $hd = new SoapVar($hdd, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);


        $headers = new \SoapHeader('http://***.***.com/PortalServices', 'UserCredentials', $hd);

        // Prepare Soap Client
        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));

        $user = new WsUser();
        // Setup the CreateUser parameters
        $ap_param = array(
        'Name' => 'Sasha Lavasov',
        'WsUser' => $user
                    );


        $param = new \SoapParam($user, 'WsUser');
        // Call CreateUser ()
        $error = 0;

        try {
        //Build user entity
        $usr  = new WsUser();
        $wsServices = new StdClass();

        $id = new StdClass();
        $id->Id = '***';
        $wsServices->WsService = $id;
        $usr->WsServices = $wsServices;

        $createUser = new stdClass();
        $createUser->user = $usr;

        $createUser = new SoapVar($createUser, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "WsUser", "http://***.***.com/PortalServices/PortalServices.asmx?op=CreateUser");

        $pm = new SoapParam($createUser, "user");

        $soapClient->CreateUser($pm);
            //Here I get xml
            var_dump( $soapClient->__getLastRequest()); die();
        } catch (\SoapFault $fault) {
            $error = 1;
            print($fault->faultcode." - ".$fault->faultstring); die();
        }

        if ($error == 0) {
        //             DO SOMETHING
            } else {

            }

         $res = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
         print_r($res); die();
```

But instead I get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://***.***.com/PortalServices/PortalServices.asmx?op=CreateUser" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://***.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://***.***.com/PortalServices">
<env:Header>

<ns3:UserCredentials>
<UserName>***</UserName>
<PassWord>***</PassWord>
<ServiceName>***</ServiceName>
</ns3:UserCredentials></env:Header>

<env:Body>
<ns2:CreateUser xsi:type="ns1:WsUser">
<user>
<Name>Sasha Lavasov</Name>
<Email>imsashko@gmail.com</Email>
<PassWord>test</PassWord>
<WsServices><WsService><Id>***</Id></WsService></WsServices>
</user>
</ns2:CreateUser>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And get FALSE as result. 
In the list of server's functions (using __getFunctions()) I've got following:

```
CreateUserResponse CreateUser(CreateUser $parameters)
```

Can anyone help me or just tell where I'm wrong?

Comment: If you make a detail comparison between the SOAP XML that you think it rocks and the poor PHP SoapClient() you dislike, the only difference were the two namespaces ns1 and ns3, which is additionally specified in your PHP code.

Comment: @sasha Can you post the WSDL too? Tnx

Comment: The problem was that I've used bad namespaces and yes, WSDL worked. But I rewrote it using CURL and proper xml. It is enough because I receive only 1 boolean response and it is easy to parse.
Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion.

In your *good* xml you've:

```
<UserCredentials xmlns="http://***.com/">
```

but in your PHP you set:

```
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://***.***.com/PortalServices', 'UserCredentials', $hd);
```

Then you've 2 different namespaces: **http://***.***.com/PortalServices** instead of **http://***.com/**